# How to read line by line after i read a text into a buffer?

Tags: c, fread

First , I read a text into a buffer by calling fread, and then I want to read it line by line, how to do it? I try to use a sscanf , but it seems not to work.

```
char textbuf[4096];
char line[256];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
memset(textbuf, 0, 4096);
fread(textbuf, 1, 4096, fp);
```

I know using fgets is a good way. I just want to know weather this method can do the same thing.

Comment: Why not use `fgets()` to read the file one line at a time?

Comment: Or `getline()` if you are on system POSIX-compatible..

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
fgets(textbuf, sizeof(textbuf), fp);
```

For read line by line you can use: `fgets(line, 128, fp)` or `getline(&line, &size, fp);`

**EDIT**

If you want to read it from a variable, look at `strtok()` function:

```
char * line = strtok(strdup(buffer), "\n");
while(line) {
   printf("%s", line);
   line  = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
```

Comment: @AdamLiss: It's depends. See that have two questions here. One can be solved using fgets() only and another can be solved by using fgets() or getline().

Comment: both fgets and getline need file poiter, so, there is no need to call fread. i want to read line by line from buffer, how ?

Comment: @ccsnailpp: something like the second code example? or want read this from a variable?

Comment: @Jack i want to read it from a variable, not from a file poiter

Answer (score 8):

You can find the location of the end-of-line character using [strchr()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) like this:

```
char *eol = strchr(line, '\n');
```

Everything before `*eol` is the first line.  Then advance from `line` to `eol + 1`, remove any subsequent `\r` or `\n` characters, and repeat the process until `strchr()` returns `NULL` to indicate there are no more newline characters.  At that point, move any remaining data to the beginning of the buffer and read the next chunk from the file.

If you're concerned about efficiency you can avoid moving the data by using 2 buffers and alternating between them, but even the naive method is probably faster than `fgets()` if the file has many lines.

Comment: best and simplest version so far!

Answer (score 2):

how about [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

```
char *line;
line = strtok(texbuf, '\n');
```

Comment: Be _very_ careful using `strtok()`.  It's not reentrant, and it modifies its input as it processes it.

Comment: @nos yeah, i have already known that, so it's just a trying. an alternative method. I think `fgets` is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You said "I know using fgets is a good way. I just want to know weather this method can do the same thing.", of course you can, you just re-implement fgets as in the c library. The c library doesn't actually read line by line, it reads in a whole chunk and gives you a line when you call fgets.

Not an efficient way, but a sample of the kind of things you have to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct my_state {
 unsigned char * buf;
 int offset;
 int buf_size;
 int left;
 FILE * file;
} my_state_t;
int takeone(my_state_t * state) {
 if ((state->left - state->offset)<=0) {
  if (feof(state->file)) return -1;
  state->left = fread(state->buf,1,state->buf_size,state->file);
  state->offset = 0;
  if (state->left == 0) return -1;
 }
 return state->buf[state->offset++];
}
int getaline(my_state_t * state, char * out, int size) {
 int c;
 c = takeone(state);
 if (c < 0) return 0;
 while (c >=0 && size > 1) {
  *out++ = c;
  --size;
  if (c == '\n') break;
  c = takeone(state);
 }
 *out=0;
 return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
 FILE *fp;
 char textbuf[4096];
 char line[256];
 my_state_t fs;
 fs.buf=textbuf;
 fs.offset=0;
 fs.buf_size=4096;
 fs.left=0;
 fp = (argc>1)? fopen(argv[1],"rb") : stdin;
 fs.file = fp;
 while (getaline(&fs,line,256)) {
  printf("-> %s", line);
 }
 fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: that's almost what i want. I nearly forget `fgets` is a libary function , not a system call.